# Dropwizard service not starting properly

Tags: dropwizard

I have created a dropwizard service. When I ran it using below command it does nothing but hang. Anything wrong with below command ?

```
java -jar helloworld-1.0.jar server helloworld.yml
```

Earlier above used to work fine. It just stopped working since last few days.

Comment: What changed in the past few days?

Comment: Really don't understand that. I rollback everything. The weird thing is that when I do "java -jar helloworld-1.0.jar se" it starts the service. What the heck is this "SE" - It is blowing my mind. Really wanted to fix this ASAP and move my project

Comment: Normally there is a log message if not working? If your yml is wrong then this is shown.

Answer (score 2):

> The weird thing is that when I do "java -jar helloworld-1.0.jar se" it
>   starts the service. What the heck is this "SE" - It is blowing my
>   mind.

`se` appears to be shorthand for `server`. You can use `s`, `se`, `ser`, and so on. `servers` doesn't work, nor does `sauron`.

If `java -jar helloworld-1.0.jar server` starts the service, but `java -jar helloworld-1.0.jar server helloworld.yml` does not, then I would have a look at your configuration file, `helloworld.yml`.